# fastAPI SQLmodel MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found when exactly one was required

Tags: fastapi, sqlmodel

This is my delete function.

```
def delete_session(self,session_id: int, db):
        with Session(engine) as session:
            statement = select(db).where(db.session == session_id)
            results = session.exec(statement)
            sess = results.one()
            print("sess: ", sess)
        if not sess:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Session not found")
        session.delete(sess)
        session.commit()
        return {"Session Deleted": True}
```

I want to delete all records where session_id matches.
But its throwing following error
`MultipleResultsFound: Multiple rows were found when exactly one was required`

How can i delete multiple rows at once.

I tried using

```
sess = results.all()
```

but it say

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.list' is not mapped
```

Thanks

Comment: Was the answer provided below able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are trying to delete several data items, except that `session.delete()` only takes a single value, not a list of values.

You are using `results.one()` probably thinking that you can isolate your answers and return only one. However, it is explained in the documentation that if multiple entries are found in the parameter passed to `one()` then it will throw a `MultipleResultsFound` exception, hence your error.

Indeed, your statement returns a list, so multiple values.

In order to delete all your elements, you should not use `one()` but simply iterate with a `for` loop on your `results` and delete one by one, your data, as follows:

```py
def delete_session(self, session_id: int, db):
    with Session(engine) as session:
        statement = select(db).where(db.session == session_id)
        results = session.exec(statement).all()
        for sess in results:
            session.delete(sess)
    session.commit()
    return {"Session Deleted": True}
```